# Eigen custom expression type (or CWise Op functor?)

Tags: c++, eigen

consider this simple function (kind of pseudo-code):

```
template <typename Derived>
void f (const MatrixBase<Derived>& input1,
        const MatrixBase<Derived>& input2,
        const MatrixBase<Derived>& input3,
        Vec6& output)
{
    part1(output) = <an expr using the three inputs>;
    part2(output) = <another expr using the three inputs>;
}
```

Where `part1` and `part2` are block expressions selecting the top 3 rows and bottom 3 rows of `output`, respectively. I know that `output` is always a column vector with 6 coefficients.

I would like to avoid passing the `output` argument. But I would also like to avoid returning an explicit `Vec6`, to avoid copies of temporaries.

Thus I would like to return one of those magical eigen expression objects, which only store a reference to the inputs and actually do the computation only when required.

My questions:

1. Is it worth it? Given that it is a "small" 6-dimensional vector (for example, the docs say that with small 3-vectors the compilers are usually able to optimize away temporaries, thus there is not much point of avoiding them)
2. Can I implement my return expression type with a custom functor and the `CWiseNullaryOp` or do I really need a custom expression type?

Thanks

---

EDIT: so we established that the temporaries are optimized away (see comments); that answers question 1, and makes 2 not relevant.

However, for the sake of curiosity and learning a bit more about Eigen, does anyone have some hints about a viable expression type for my function? (assuming it was worth to devise one)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Vec6 has been designed "properly" (See *e.g.* [Rule Of Zero](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-zero.html)) then if your function `f()` takes the form

```c
Vec6 f(const MatrixBase<Derived>& input1,
       const MatrixBase<Derived>& input2,
       const MatrixBase<Derived>& input3)
{
    Vec6 answer;

    //Manipulate answer
    //...

    return answer; 
}
```

then **with optimization enabled on most modern compilers** no copy will happen. See the Wikipedia section on Return Value Optimization [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization).

(To test the theory with your object and compiler, you could wrap a Vec6 in your own class, make all constructors print when they are executed, and check you are getting the number of constructor calls you expect.)

Comment: I just had a play with a toy example using g++ version 7.4. It basically did copy elision (as I expected), but even without optimization enabled. To explicitly disable it, you would set the flag `-fno-elide-constructors`. This yields temporary copies being constructed and destroyed, which is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Thanks @ianinini. My `Vec6` is just `eigen::Matrix<double, 6,1>`, so I guess it qualifies as "designed properly". I will repeat your experiment to see the copy elision myself.

Comment: @L. Bruce I also believe Eigen to be well designed (but don't use it myself) so you're almost certainly correct.

Comment: I can confirm @ianinini findings, the temporaries are optimized away even without the `-O` option (I used g++ 5.4). The switch `-fno-elide-constructors`, on the other hand, forces the copy-constructors and the temporaries.